# Swift: how to declare a strong reference to reference self in a closure

Tags: swift, closures

I want to fire a request from Alamofire and using some methods of the class to handle the response. What works:

```
// inside a class that has _handleError, _handleServerError
//and handleJsonResponse methods
func connect() {
    let me = self
    Alamofire.request(.GET,
        "http://httpbin.org/get")
    .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if let errorInstance = error? {
            me._hanldeError(errorInstance)
            return
        }
        if response!.statusCode != 200 {
            me._handleServerError(response!)
            return
        }
        me._handleJsonResponse(json!)
    }
}
```

This is nice but I have a strange love/hate relationship with that `let me = self`, I would like to be able to use self there. I don't want to use a weak / unowned reference but a strong one but I don't know 
how to declare it:

That works for a weak reference (similar thing for unowned):

```
[weak self] (request, response, json, error) in
```

This doesn't work:

```
[self] (request, response, json, error) in
```

This neither:

```
[strong self] (request, response, json, error) in
```

The message, funnily, is: `Expected "strong", "weak" or "unowned" specifier in capture list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably even funnier than the question: don't even bother if what you want is a strong reference to self (maybe I did too much JavaScript), it's already here.

```
// inside a class that has _handleError, _handleServerError
//and handleJsonResponse methods
func connect() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET,
        "http://httpbin.org/get")
    .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if let errorInstance = error? {
            self._hanldeError(errorInstance)
            return
        }
        if response!.statusCode != 200 {
            self._handleServerError(response!)
            return
        }
        self._handleJsonResponse(json!)
    }
}
```